# Problem Editing Startup Applications with Gnome Tweak tool

Tags: gnome

I recently got Gnome working and was doing some customization.

I managed to get into this menu:
[Startup Applications Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVNWn.png)

Upon clicking the + symbol, nothing popped up.
No little window or anything.

Anyone know a way to fix this?